# Snakemake how to set qsub ppn per task?

Tags: snakemake, qsub

I start Snakemake on our qsub cluster like this:

```
snakemake -s Snakefile.snakefile --cluster-config cluster.json --cluster "qsub -l nodes={cluster.nodes}:ppn={cluster.ppn}" --jobs 70
```

cluster.json looks like this:

```
{
"__default__" :
{
    "cluster"   : "qsub",
    "jobs"      : 70 ,
    "nodes"     : 1,
    "ppn"       : 8
},
```

}

For some rules I have set threads to 8, but for some I set it to 1 (like some RSeQC modules, like this rule:

```
rule bam_stat:
input:
    rseqc_input_bam
output:
    os.path.join(rseqc_dir, '{sample}.bam_stat.txt')
threads: 1
shell:
    '''
    #!/bin/bash
    # Enter the Python 2 conda environment where rseqc is installed
    source activate rseqc
    bam_stat.py -i {input} > {output}
    '''
```

Now if I look in my clusters queuing system it tells me this job still reserves 8 cores, as if submitted with --nodes=1,ppn=8

How do I set the ppn per individual task?

Highest regards,

Freek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, `rule_X` will use 12 ppn unlike other rules which use set default of 8.

```
{
    "__default__" :
    {
        "cluster"   : "qsub",
        "jobs"      : 70 ,
        "nodes"     : 1,
        "ppn"       : 8
    },

    "rule_X" :
    {
        "ppn"       : 12
    },

}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanx! Of course this keeps better with the philosophy of keeping cluster related things in cluster.json/yaml. The "threads" parameter is purely something you can input into your shell script and has nothing to do with qsub, apparently.